# Preencher val de uma classe que é criada dinamicamente

Tags: javascript

Estou fazendo uma requisição, cujo com esse retorno, eu crio uma classe com o nome do retorno com o atributo data para ser o valor que eu quero realizar o calculo.

Ele fica assim

Não vou por a requisição toda que está enorme e não vem ao caso

```
dados = $.parseJSON(data);
$.each(dados,function (key) {
      $(".dataImposto").append(" <div class='row static-info align-reverse'> <div class='col-md-8 name '>"+dados[key].nome+" ("+dados[key].valor+"%)</div> <div id='imposto' class='col-md-3 value "+dados[key].nome.replace( /\s/g, '' ) + " ' data-class="+dados[key].nome.replace( /\s/g, '' )+" data-imposto="+dados[key].valor+" > </div> </div>");
});
```

Ele me gera como resultado algo do tipo

```html
<div class="dataImposto">
  <div class="row static-info align-reverse">
    <div class="col-md-8 name "> DAS(11.50 % )
    </div>
    <div id="imposto" class="col-md-3 value DAS" data-class="DAS" data-imposto="11.50"> </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row static-info align-reverse">
    <div class="col-md-8 name ">Imposto de Renda (15.00%)</div>
    <div id="imposto" class="col-md-3 value ImpostodeRenda" data-class="ImpostodeRenda" data-imposto="15.00">
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

O meu problema está quando eu tento escrever na classe gerada ImpostodeRenda por exemplo, ele me da um retorno de **undefined**

Como solucionar isso?

Edit 1:

```
 //faz a soma
  valueSubTotal = parseFloat((totalLicenciamentos + totalOpcionais + totalGateways + totalHardwarePag + valUpdate + totalGarantia) - totalSuporte);
  //exibe a soma no formato $0.000,00, não é gerado dinamicamente, aparece         

$(".valueSubTotal").text(parseFloat(valueSubTotal, 10).toFixed(2).replace(/[.]/g, ",").replace(/\d(?=(?:\d{3})+(?:\D|$))/g, "$&.").toString());

  //valor gerado dinamicamente, não aparece
  $(".ImpostodeRenda").attr("data-class", "teste")
```

Comment: Como você está tentando "escrever"?

Comment: Iria pegar dinamicamente esse valor, mas $(".nomeClass").val(valor);

Comment: Não deveria ser html() ao invés de val()?

Comment: Com html() não funcionou **$(".ImpostodeRenda").html("ddd");**

Comment: @gabrielfalieri O retorno `undefined` não tem nada a ver com a classe gerada. Muito provavelmente alguma dessas variáveis que você usa nas contas está `undefined` porque não foi recuperada corretamente, então você soma `undefined` com qualquer coisa e o resultado é `undefined` também. Fiz um exemplo bem simples que ilustra que em geral o código funciona. Veja [aqui](https://jsfiddle.net/utluiz/fm1axcza/).

Comment: Você pode encontrar uma explicação simples sobre como manipular elementos dinâmicos neste link: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/249005/input-adicionado-com-append-n%C3%A3o-envia-os-dados-post/249040#249040